# Parallel.ForEach not storing data in variable accurately

Tags: c#, file, parallel.foreach

First off, I apologize for the title, I am unsure of how to word this question.

I currently have a `Parallel.ForEach` looping through a directory filled with .txt files.

What I am doing inside of this is grabbing specific data that varies from file-to-file.

Whenever all of the needed data is grabbed, it is then outputted to a file.

Everything is accurate except for the ID numbers inside each text file. The ID numbers are not lining up with their corresponding file. It's outputted in an arbitrary manner. The names and date's line up fine, but not the actual ID numbers inside of the text files. I am unsure of how to proceed with this as the code looks fine to me. The only thing I can think of is `AppendAllText` is consistently opening and closing the final text file, which in turn disallows accurate data to be outputted. Below is my code.

```
        Parallel.ForEach(directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.txt"), (file, state) =>
        {
            using StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(file.FullName);
            string user = sr.ReadToEnd();
            if (user.Contains("ID:"))
            {
                ID = IDRegex.Match(user).Value.Replace("ID:", string.Empty);

            }
            else if (user.Contains("ID="))
            {
                ID = IDDRegex.Match(user).Value.Replace("ID=", string.Empty);
            }

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                //count++;
                //Current.Content = file.Name;
                if (user.Contains(users.Text))
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(Idir + "IReport-" + IUser.Text + ".txt",
                                       String.Format("{0,-16} {1,27}", file.Name.Replace(".txt", ""), (file.LastWriteTime.Date).ToString()).Replace("12:00:00 AM", "") +
                                       String.Format("{0, 18}", ID) + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Why `Dispatcher.Invoke`?

Comment: @dymanoid So my UI doesn't freeze up when it's processing and writing the data.

Comment: What is `ID`? Is it a field? A local variable? What type is it? When do you actually use it?

Comment: Ouch, sorry I didn't update the variable's name. `ID` stores the the ID number that's within the text file (it's a string.) If you see on `File.AppendText`. Sorry about that @JohnWu

@dymanoid I cloned that from another method within this application. I haven't removed anything that's unnecessary yet from this method. Unless you have a belief that `Dispatcher.Invoke` could be causing the issue?

Comment: If `ID` is declared outside your `Parallel.ForEach` block, that means it is a shared variable that all the different threads are going to try to update at about the same time. It wouldn't be surprising if your code set it to one value and it was output into the file with a different value. I suggest moving its declaration to the inside of the loop so that each thread has its own copy.

Comment: Thank you for the information. This gives me some leads on what could be modifying that variable. I'll update this post if I find the resolution.

Comment: @JohnWu, you also had the same resolution that worked. Thank you as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that because you've used `Parallel.ForEach()`, the code you've posted is being run multiple times simutaneously by different threads. This is great for doing the work faster, but it can catch you out a few ways.

Your variable `ID` is not declared in the code you've posted, which means it must be coming from somewhere else. This means that all the threads created by your use of `Parallel.ForEach()` are sharing the same variable, overwriting each other's values, which is what you're seeing: the ID being written to the file isn't the one for this file, it's one from whichever thread happens to have touched that value most recently.

Declare a fresh variable *inside* your call to `Parallel.ForEach()` to use as the ID, and all threads will have their own value that the others can't mess with. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Trying now, one moment. Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, I was over-thinking what you were describing. This fixed the issue. Thank you.